# Android Runnable find run caller

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I have inherited an enormous and horrible Android project that reminds me of [this post](http://thejoysofcode.tumblr.com/post/35824954456/when-i-open-a-folder-that-contains-code-from-an-intern).

In this project there is a mysterious Activity that implements Runnable. The run function is failing because the Activity is not correctly initialized. My problem is I have no idea where the Runnable is actually run.

How can I find the point where the Runnable interface of this Activity is called? Breakpoints just seem to show the parent Thread calling run() - wow, surprise.

Comment: remove `implements Runnable`, rename the `run` method and see what the compiler tells you where it is used

Comment: beautiful. Got it. Make an answer and I'll vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is I have no idea where the Runnable is actually run.

If the `Runnable` is used in a `Thread`, there should be code like `new Thread(someObject)` that you try to find.

The constructor expects a `Runnable` and if you remove the `implements Runnnable` part from the class, the code that creates the `Thread` is now incorrect and results in a compiler error that should tell you what you look for.

In case someone is calling the `run` method directly you can rename it and the compiler will tell you which places call a method that does not exist. Alternatively

```
Exception e = new Exception("Debug");
e.fillInstackTrace();
e.printStackTrace();
```

is a quick way to show the call-hierarchy in code without using a debugger or an advanced IDE like Eclipse. That's sometimes nice to put in a problematic execution branch in the method to find who is causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the reference for the Activity class name in the project... May be some class is creating the object of Activity explicitly...